# c# Outlook dynamic automation SendUsingAccount failing

Tags: c#, outlook, automation

I am trying to send an email from my application using a user specified account.
For some reason, SendUsingAccount stays null and the default account is used.

I am using late binding to prevent version conflicts.
This is using VS2012, .net framework 4.5

```
dynamic email = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application"));
dynamic mail = email.CreateItem(0);

        //setup main details
        mail.To = "me@gmail.com";
        mail.Subject = "Test Email from C#";
        mail.HTMLBody = "<p>Is this thing on?</p><br/>";

        //get account required
        dynamic acc = email.Session.Accounts;
        dynamic useAcc = acc[1];
        for (int i = 1; i <= acc.Count; i++)
        {
            if (acc[i].DisplayName.ToString().ToLower() == "test@office.com")
            {
                useAcc = acc[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        acc = null;

        mail.SendUsingAccount = useAcc;

        mail.Send()
```

It is finding the correct account and looks like it is setting it, but it refuses to use an account other than the default account (which is not the same as the one I am checking for)

Trying the same thing with early binding works fine

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What happens if you comment out the Send line and replace it with Save()? If you then look at the message with OutlookSpy (click the Item button), does the SendUsingAccount property have the expected value?

Comment: @Dimtry - The value is null??? Also thanks for pointing out OutlookSpy, looks like it can be a very useful developing tool

Comment: So is it null because you set it to null? Or does it turn to null if you read it back immediately after setting it?

Comment: I ran it in debug mode, when it gets set, it stays null (and the acc value is not null).
Perhaps it needs to be cast, but I have no clue to what it needs to be cast as since I am using dynamic

Comment: Have you tried to use Outlook.MailItem instead of dynamic?

Comment: I can't use that as I cannot ensure the users will have the same version of Outlook

Comment: All versions of Outlook are backward compatible - just use the interop from the lowest supported version of Outlook.

Comment: While this doesn't address the issue, thanks for that advice, it is gold! Thank you, I will do so

Comment: Do you still see the problem when using early binding?

Comment: No, as I said in my post, early binding works perfectly

Comment: I am confused - you are using "dynamic", which is late binding. Declaring as MailItem is early binding, but you have not tried that. Is this wrong?

Comment: I used early binding in a different test project just to make sure that I was doing things correctly, and SendUsingAccount works as expected.
In this live project I did the same thing with late binding, without the outlook references, and SendUsingAccount is not behaving the way it behaved in the test project.
This is what I am asking for help for

Comment: Ok, so why not use early binding in the project you are having problems in?

Comment: I will have to use early binding to get this working. I was just hoping to get this working with late binding to ensure no version issues.
But as you said before, I will just have to use the lowest version and hope for the best

Comment: Maybe you do not have the permission to send the message on behalf of the specified user. Contact your network administrator. @Arkaine80

Comment: Hi Goluk
I am not in a domain, and like I said earlier, I am able to do this using early binding. This is however potentially a useful thing to check if anyone else has this issue